# Открытие wordpress

Tags: wordpress, интерфейс, веб-сайт, connection

Создал сайт `digitalshop.ru` в вордпрессе, но при открытии возникает ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

В ошибке всё сказано. В файле wp-config.php указаны имя базы данных, пользователя базы данных и пароль. Если что-то из этого некорректно, то будет подобного рода ошибка, как сейчас.